# Module preservation analysis WGCNA

Tags: r, rna-seq

I have done a WGCNA (weighted gene co-expression network analysis) analysis for various brain disorders. So along with control, I have 3 different disorders such as BPD, MDD and SCZ. Now I have to find out what sort of modules are preserved between the control and disease condition.

I have 54 samples in control and 50 samples in MDD as one of the condition. The other conditions are similar, somewhere between 50-60 samples each.

I have cited a paper where they have done module preservation analysis. Now I have checked the WGCNA or website they do have given example of mouse male and female liver module preservation.

I am stuck at this do I need both the expression data together to do module preservation analysis? Or do I first have to run WCGNA on both the data sets and then look for?

For example if I want to look at what are the modules preserved in CTRL and BPD condition.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Eyandell/statgen/ucla/WGCNA/wgcna.html) section **12.5 Module preservation between female and male mice**

where it reads both male and female data together which is bit confusing

```
maleData = read.csv(file.path(data.dir, "LiverMaleFromLiverFemale3600.csv"))
```

I have also followed this tutorial:

https://horvath.genetics.ucla.edu/html/CoexpressionNetwork/ModulePreservation/Tutorials/

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

[Weighted gene network coexpression analysis (WGCNA) reveals stage-specific modules (gene network) in neonatal left and right ventricles](https://insight.jci.org/articles/view/94904/figure/2)